# How to call Oracle Procedure which has one OUT parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

My oracle procedure structure,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY NLS_ADMIN."MY_PKG"
AS

   PROCEDURE DATA_PRC (oresult  OUT   NUMBER )
   IS
      varKeyValue   varchar2(1);
   BEGIN
     ...
     ...
   END;
```

I tried to call above procedure by executing below statement,

```
declare
   oresult  NUMBER;
begin
   EXECUTE DATA_PRC(oresult);
end;
```

But getting below exception. Please help me how to call this procedure.

```
ORA-06550: line 8, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DATA_PRC" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ; immediate
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "DATA_PRC" to continue.
```

Comment: First of all, drop the execute, it's SQL*PLUS command, not the PL/SQL statement. Secondly, as your procedure is placed in a package it has to be qualified with the package name when referenced (`my_pkg.data_prc`). Thirdly, be sure the declaration of the procedure is present in the package specification as well, otherwise the procedure is local to the package body, meaning you won't be able to reference it outside the package body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply this:

```
declare
   oresult  NUMBER;
begin
   MY_PKG.DATA_PRC(oresult);
end;
```